# Twitter4j Getting Tweets Too Long

Tags: database, twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-search

Hello i have tweet id's and i saved them to database before. But i saw that i could not save created time efficiently (it is saved like 00:00:00). Therefore i wished to update my tweets with tweet id by using following code.

```
   MyConnectionBuilder myConnection = new MyConnectionBuilder();
   Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory(myConnection.configuration.build()).getInstance();
    Status status = twitter.showStatus(Long.parseLong(tweetId));
```

But it takes too much time to get tweets, is there any rate limit for this ? If there is a rate limit how can i make it faster ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating every single tweet via `showStatus` wastes your "credits" for a given timeframe (rate-limit).

For updating multiple tweets, you should use `lookup` with a maximum of `100` ids per request. This call will use the `/statuses/lookup` endpoint.

Rate-Limit and endpoint documentation can be found [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/lookup)

Code-Snipped for it:

```
Twitter twitter =  twitterFactory.getInstance();
ResponseList<Status> responseList  = twitter.lookup(ArrayUtils.toPrimitive(ids));

    if(responseList != null) {
        for (Status status : responseList) {
            // do what you need to do here

        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello thanks for reply, i will try but what will be input for ids , array ? or list ? i tried but i couldnt find exact input for it. @rzo

Comment: Basic Input is Array. Example uses List or Set of Long Values.

Comment: i modified it to be long[] and i removed Arrayutils.toPrimitive method in lookup method i just put my long[] array. Can it be a problem ? @rzo

Comment: http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TweetsResources.html#lookup-long...- long array should be fine.

Comment: hi , i could not get any result ,                                        ResponseList<Status> responseList  = twitter.lookup(myIdArray);
System.out.println(responseList.size());    size printed as zero. @rzo , what should i do ? thanks for your interest